# Can't open my PyCharm app in Windows 10 PC?

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm app is not running on my PC for 6 months. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling many times. I also updated it many times. I clear all the broken registries and tried troubleshooting, I tried changing the older compatible version of windows but still, I can't open it. It is the only app on my PC which is not running. Whenever I try to open it, nothing happens. It does not show a single error box or a word. Also, I cant open all the related files in it. Here it shows when I try to run it from CMD.

```java
C:\Users\Rishabh Semwal>pycharm
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and 
will likely be removed in a future release.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(java.base/Charset.java:455)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(java.base/Charset.java:608)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(java.base/StringCoding.java:316)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:592)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:614)
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(java.base/Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:1948)
```

Comment: What is the output of `chcp` command on the CMD?

Comment: C:\Users\Rishabh Semwal>chcp
                                                                                                                    
Active code page: 65001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: `Control Panel` `->` `Clock and Region` `->` `"Change date, time or number formats"` (under Region) `->` go to Administrative tab `->` click on `"Change system locale..."` (under `"Langauge for non-Unicode programs"`) `->` un-tick `"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"` `->` click `"OK"` `->` click `"Apply"`.-

Once this is saved, restart your computer. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" is already ticked, brother. What to do next?

Comment: And if you uncheck it, restart PC and try again?

Comment: I can't uncheck it. Every time I uncheck it and click OK then Restart, I found it again checked. I tried several other combinations of steps to uncheck it and start pycharm but failed. It gets uncheck only for the time when I hit first Ok. After I click Ok on Region window, it get checked again

Comment: Is there any misconfiguration in my environment?

Comment: You need admin rights to change it. Can you search for CMD, then right click, select "Run as administrator", when CMD opens type in "control" and try unticking it there.

Comment: I tried to uncheck this the way you suggested but I failed. Then I enable safe mode. But to my horror, there is no Region option in control panel. Please tell me the other ways to uncheck this box

Comment: The problem is now solved. After I change the system locale to English (US), I became able to uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". After restarting the PC, Pycharm start working again.